# How to view 360 degree images in Unreal Engine 4

Tags: unreal-4, image

Is there any way I can view 360 degree images in UE4, Ive read about possibly mapping it onto a hollow sphere however it always seems warped. I am working on a virtual tour and would like to be able to transition between multiple 360 images such as the ones found here : http://www.wpanorama.com/panoramas.php?page=01n . I am new to Unreal Engine and any help would be greatly appreciated. Ideally I would like to have it mapped to a sky sphere with the image on the sky sphere changing based on the "point" the user clicks on however I am not sure how I could go about this.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to map a 360-degree environment to a flat image.

In this case, the WPanorama images look like they were mapped cylindrically, so map it to the sides of a cylinder around your camera and it avoids the "warped" look. As you can see from the source images, they don't include "ground" or "overhead sky" so mapping it to a sphere would distort the image.

Comment: Ah this is certainly getting rid of the distortion and making the image look correct as far as rotation goes. Now i just need to figure out how to deal with the ground and sky portions

Comment: If you want maps with ground and sky portions, you'll have to find source material that includes it. Usually those images will be cubemaps (they contain the 6 faces of a cube, including the top and bottom) or a spheremap (they look like your cylindrical maps but extend all the way to "vertical" in both directions ) [example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126399/how-to-project-a-spherical-map-onto-a-sphere-cube]